# Why type deduction of decltype(auto) from element of rvalue int vector is int&?

Tags: c++, return-type-deduction

The following code results 0100 (complied with CLang, GNU++14). I would expect 0001, because func takes rvalue vector as parameter, then forward(c)[0] is const reference of int, so type deduction of decltype(auto) should result to const int&. Please help me understand the result. Thanks!

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) func(T&& c)
{
    return forward<T>(c)[0];
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    cout
    << is_same< int, decltype(func(vector<int>{3}))>::value
    << is_same< int&, decltype(func(vector<int>{3}))>::value
    << is_same< const int, decltype(func(vector<int>{3}))>::value
    << is_same< const int&, decltype(func(vector<int>{3}))>::value
    << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0100
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`c` is an rvalue reference.

`[]` has a `const` and non-`const` overload.  When passed a vector of type `vector<T,A>&&`, the overload selected is the non-`const` one.

`[]` could be changed (to have a `&&` overload that returns a value or rvalue), but of so it could break existing code.  So probably this won't happen until `std2` at least, which allows for breaking revisions in `std` without breaking existing code.

Comment: `std2`? Never heard about that before. Have you any reference to point out? Thank you. Also, I guess the question was about the fact that with `decltype(auto)` you get the actual type, that is `U&` for `operator[]` and not `U`.

Comment: @skypjack compiler actually returned `int&`, OP expected `const int&`.

Comment: @A.S.H Oh, I see. Missed the comment in the question. Sorry.

Comment: @skyjack `std[0-9]*` was reserved for future use in C++17.